# MacOs table with SwiftUI: NSTableView, NSViewControllerRepresentable and Core data update

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, nstableview

I'm creating a personal bank account app for MacOS.
I want to display a table with transactions. I started using `List`, but columns were not well aligned.
I changed to `NSTableView` wrapped in `NSViewControllerRepresentable`. It's working fine. But when I save the core data, the table is not updating.
Now I want to connect the core data update to the `NSTableView` update to see the changes in the table.

How to do this?

**AccountTransactionTableView:**

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import CoreData
import Cocoa

struct AccountTransactionTableView: NSViewControllerRepresentable {
    typealias NSViewControllerType = AccountTransactionTableViewController

    @State var showSettingsModalView: Bool = false

    let account: BankAccount
    let month: Int
    let year: Int

    init(account: BankAccount, month: Int, year: Int) {
        self.account = account
        self.month = month
        self.year = year
    }

    func makeNSViewController(context: Context) -> AccountTransactionTableViewController {
        return AccountTransactionTableViewController(account: account, month: month, year: year)
    }

    func updateNSViewController(_ nsViewController: AccountTransactionTableViewController, context: Context) {

    }
}
```

**AccountTransactionTableViewController:**

```
class AccountTransactionTableViewController: NSViewController, NSTableViewDelegate, NSTableViewDataSource {
    let account: AbstractAccount
    @FetchRequest<TransactionEntry> private var entries: FetchedResults<TransactionEntry>

    var initialized = false
    let scrollView = NSScrollView()
    let tableView = NSTableView()
    let startDate: Date
    let endDate: Date

    init(account: AbstractAccount, month: Int, year: Int) {
        self.account = account

        self.startDate = DateTool.firstDayOfMonth(year: year, month: month)
        self.endDate = DateTool.endOfMonth(year: year, month: month)

        self._entries = FetchRequest<TransactionEntry>(
            entity: TransactionEntry.entity(),
            sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \TransactionEntry.transaction!.date, ascending: true)],
            predicate: NSPredicate(format: "account.name == %@ and transaction.date >= %@ and transaction.date <= %@", account.name!, startDate as CVarArg, endDate as CVarArg)
        )

        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    override func loadView() {
        self.view = NSView()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func viewDidLayout() {
        if !initialized {
            initialized = true
            setupView()
            setupTableView()
        }
    }

    func setupView() {
        self.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
    }

    func setupTableView() {
(...)
    }

    func numberOfRows(in tableView: NSTableView) -> Int {
        return entries.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView? {
        let entry = entries.map { $0 }[row]
        let transactionCell = AccountTransactionCell(entry: entry, account: account, collapsed: false)
        let cell = NSTableCellView()
    
        let text = NSTextField()
        switch tableColumn!.identifier.rawValue {
        case "date":
            text.stringValue = "\(transactionCell.date)"
        case "category":
            text.stringValue = "\(transactionCell.category)"
        case "details":
            text.stringValue = "\(transactionCell.details)"
        case "debits":
            text.stringValue = "\(transactionCell.debit)"
            text.alignment = .right
        case "credits":
            text.stringValue = "\(transactionCell.credit)"
            text.alignment = .right
        default:
            text.stringValue = "-"
        }

        cell.addSubview(text)
        text.drawsBackground = false
        text.isBordered = false
        text.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        cell.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: text, attribute: .left, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: cell, attribute: .left, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
        cell.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: text, attribute: .right, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: cell, attribute: .right, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, rowViewForRow row: Int) -> NSTableRowView? {
        let rowView = NSTableRowView()
        rowView.isEmphasized = false
        return rowView
    }
}
```

`AccountTransactionCell` is a formatter struct.

Thanks for your help :-)

Answer (score 1):

#### You must call `tableView.reloadData()` once the save has settled in Core Data.

Good Explanation here:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstableview/1528382-reloaddata

A possibility for where you may want to call this is in the function provided for you by the `NSViewControllerRepresentable`:

```
func updateNSViewController(_ nsViewController: AccountTransactionTableViewController, context: Context) {
    nsViewController.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

***IMPORTANT:*** the above will only be called if the Representable contains a reference to the data backing the table (aka the `@FetchRequest private var entries` lives in your Representable Class instead of the AppKit class.)

If you would like to keep the `@FetchRequest` property wrapper inside the AppKit ViewController, then you will have to observe the change to the `entries` var another way that the object can be made aware, or hook into a different event and call `reloadData()` another way.